# How can I use a wildcard alias for file names in apache config?

Tags: http, apache2, apache, httpd.conf

I need apache to call file.php when either of the following urls are called:

- /file.xml
- /file-contents.xml
- /file-abc.xml
- /file-*n*.xml
- /file-xyz.xml

Here's a sample from my apache conf file: (the second to last line is the critical one)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /html
    ServerName domain.com

    UseCanonicalName Off

    Alias /file.xml /html/file.php
    Alias /file-contents.xml /html/file.php
    Alias /file-*.xml /html/file.php
</VirtualHost>
```

I can get file.xml and file-contents.xml to call file.php just fine.  But wildcards aren't working.

What do you recommend?

---

**ANSWER:**

Thanks to Marc B!

```
AliasMatch ^/file-(.*).xml /html/file.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AliasMatch` allows regexes for this sort of thing: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch